# What is the key to getting your site accepted by the Open Directory Project?

Tags: seo, directory, directory-listing

I have tried several times over the past year to submit my site to the open directory project http://www.dmoz.org/.  Every time I check back a few months later and the site hasn't been added.  Is there a trick to getting a site accepted.  What has worked for other people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Follow the [submission guidelines](http://www.dmoz.org/add.html)

That's it. There is nothing you can do but hope your category has an editor, they are active, and they approve your site. You can ask for information in their support forums but that doesn't really do anything for you.

What you shouldn't do is resubmit your site repeatedly. That's a great way to make sure you are never accepted.

My advice to you: submit your site and forget about it. With a little luck you'll get in. But i wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: The problem with DMOZ is that there is never any notice that your site has been approved or denied. Three months down the line, you have no idea if your site was rejected or that no one has even checked it yet. It's gotta be one of the least transparent services out there.

Comment: This has been my biggest problem with it.  If it was rejected and you never submit again, it will never be accepted.